# how to add TTL value of a key in hset in Redis(Jedis)

Tags: redis, jedis

I have set a key with an expire timer using:

```
SETEX mykey 200 "Hello"
```

I want to add the value of TTL mykey to hset:

```
hset myhash f1 TTL mykey
```

But, it shows the following error:

> ERR wrong number of arguments for HMSET

I am trying to implement this functionality using **Jedis**,is there any solution specific to **jedis**?

Comment: You can't set a TTL for a field inside a Redis Hash...

Comment: Actually I want to maintain a list of keys and we can block/unblock each key.There is a requirement that each blocked key should be unblocked after 10 seconds automatically, please suggest how to achieve this functionality?Thank you for your time

Comment: You can represent a blocked key with another key, the latter having a ttl. The existence of the latter, indicates that the former is blocked. E.g. if you key is "mykey", to block it you create another key called "blocked:mykey" and set a TTL of 10 on that. Any update logic will first have to first call "EXISTS blocked:mykey" to get the status. Beware of race conditions, and avoid them by using Lua...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get TTL value of some key and put it to a hash? Then try this:

```
EVAL 'local ttl=redis.call("ttl",KEYS[1]) redis.call("hset","myhash",KEYS[2],ttl)' 2 mykey f1
```

This script gets TTL value of `mykey` (1st argument) and puts it into `myhash` field `f1` (2nd argument).

> 127.0.0.1:6370> SETEX mykey 2000 "Hello"
>   OK
>   127.0.0.1:6370> eval 'local ttl=redis.call("ttl",KEYS[1]) redis.call("hset","myhash",KEYS[2],ttl)' 2 mykey f1
>   (nil)
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hget myhash f1
>   "1861"

### Update

What you described in comment is another thing. Here is the design I suggest:
along with your data key x create a lock key x:lock when needed. Do write operations only via custom LUA, that checks the key.

- LOCK `eval 'local l=redis.call("get",KEYS[1]..":lock") if (l==false) then redis.call("setex",KEYS[1]..":lock",10,"t") return 1 end return 0' 1 mykey`
- UNLOCK `del mykey:lock`
- SETEX (lock-aware) `eval 'local l=redis.call("get",KEYS[1]..":lock") if (l==false) then return redis.call("setex",KEYS[1],KEYS[2],KEYS[3]) end return nil' 3 mykey 2000 Hello`. It will return `OK` if succeded or `(nil)` when not.

Comment: The command returns a constant number, can't it return the actual updated value of TTL?

Comment: @Saurabh sure, change it to `'local ttl=redis.call("ttl",KEYS[1]) redis.call("hset","myhash",KEYS[2],ttl) return ttl'`

Comment: Btw, are you aware, that this will be static value and it will not update over time?

Comment: For the scheme you described in comments I'd use not a hash, but rather a key with ttl 10 and with ':lock' added to original key name.